# $_FILES is empty using Yii 1.1 POST API

Tags: php, file-upload, yii, http-post, multipart

I'm trying to upload a file within POST API call.
But $_FILES is always empty!

The file I'm uploading is very tiny image, so it's not exceeding limit issue.
I'm not sure if it's a general issue or a yii related issue.

I've tried with both Postman and AdvancedRestClient but got the same empty array for: `var_dump($_FILES);`

Also tried on my local machine and on a shared hosting but also the same.

**Update:**

```
public function saveFile($fName)
{
    $postData = fopen($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], "r");
    $extension = substr($_FILES['image']['name'], strrpos($_FILES['image']['name'], '.'));
    $filename = 'pics/' . $fName . $extension;
    $fp = fopen($filename, "w");
    while ($data = fread($postData, 1024)) {
        fwrite($fp, $data);
    }
    fclose($fp);
    fclose($postData);
    return $fName . $extension;
}
```

I'm using a normal snippet to save the image.
I think the problem is not in the image saving, but with not seeing the sent files by the request.

**Update**

I've used another framework (not Yii) and got a correct value for $_FILES:

```
    array(1) { ["image"]=> array(5) { ["name"]=> string(9) "qmark.jpg" ["type"]=> string(10) "image/jpeg" 
["tmp_name"]=> string(24) "C:\xampp\tmp\php29DE.tmp" ["error"]=> int(0) ["size"]=> int(436656) } }
```

So it's something I'm doing wrong in Yii.
I'm not having UI, just a POST API (actionAdd).
Any reason why I'm getting $_FILES empty?

Comment: What are your file elements in your form. check if there is a naming issue with multiple file fields.

Comment: Can you share your code ?

Comment: I've updated my question. I'm not using a form, just sending files using POST API.

Comment: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-multipartformdataparser.html

Comment: Thanks @Deadooshka, but I'm using Yii1.1. Can it be .htaccess file issue? I don't know how it is recommended to be like.

Comment: Have you set enctype attribute to "multipart/form-data" in the form tag? <form action="/upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

Comment: It's just POST API, no UI at all. It will be invoked from android or iOS. Simply I'm testing using this: `public function actionAdd()
    {
        var_dump($_FILES);
    }`

Comment: Start by checking if there is a redirect issued somewhere (browser dev tools, network panel.) If the browser gets redirected on the POST request, and (based on the status code) requests a different URL per GET afterwards, then your POST data would be lost.

Comment: @Deadooshka you can write down your comment as answer. I think it's time to move to Yii 2.0

Answer (score 0):

The form has the attribute enctype="multipart/form-data" ?

Answer (score 0):

https://www.webslesson.info/2017/02/upload-file-without-using-form-submit-in-ajax-php.html

this tutorial can help you to upload image file without using form and eny ..

also i use of fwrite like this that maybe can help you

```
            if( Yii::$app->session['length'] <= 4 ){

            if( $success['ok']!= false ){

                $root= $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
                $file = fopen($root.'/web/uploads/'.$filename.$success['ext'], 'w+');
                fwrite($file,base64_decode($_POST['pic_file']));
                fclose($file);
                Yii::$app->session['pic_available']-=1;
                Yii::$app->session['pic_file'].=$filename.$success['ext'];

            }
        }
```

and advanced version is:

```
                $root= $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
                $file = fopen($root.'/web/uploads/'.$filename.$success['ext'], 'w+');
                $content = $_POST['pic_file'];

                $pieces = str_split(base64_decode($content), 1024 * 4);             
                foreach ($pieces as $piece) {

                    fwrite($file, $piece, strlen($piece));

                }

                fclose($file);
                Yii::$app->session['pic_available']-=1;
                Yii::$app->session['pic_file'].=$filename.$success['ext'].'|';
```